# How to control user type when user try to login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have two user type. After destroy app I want to go to two activity for two user type. With my method I cant access current user because user is not logined

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

  if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

       if(loginflag.equals("0")){
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeUsers.class));
            finish();
        }
        else if (loginflag.equals("1"))  {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeEducator.class));
            finish();
           }
        }
    }


private void loginControl() {

    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    String id = user.getUid();
    DatabaseReference FirebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(id);

    FirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            if(snapshot.exists()){
                loginflag = snapshot.child("flag").getValue().toString();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
   auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

        String id = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        DatabaseReference FirebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(id);

        FirebaseRef.child("flag").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    String loginflag = snapshot.getValue().toString();

                    if (loginflag.equals("0")) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeUsers.class));
                        finish();
                    } else if (loginflag.equals("1")) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeEducator.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) You save my hours

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need to add under each user inside your database a flag named `userType`. Then when the users is loggin in, check what kind of user is, to know to which activity you need to redirect it. The logic should be as follows:

```
if(userModel.getUserType().equals("homeUser")) {
    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeUsers.class));
    finish();
} else if (userModel.getUserType().equals("homeEducator")) {
    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeEducator.class));
    finish();
}
```